# Are there any good idea to fetch array from server prior to render function?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch objects from realtimedatabase,and make value checkboxes list.
it worked with  substituting object directly for React child component's props without using firebase.
However,when object is fetched from firebase and then substituted  for props,it doesn't work. I think it is caused async is not working well because render rendering is faster than fetching  object from firebase.

**Are there any good idea to fetch object prior to render?**

thanks.

firebase config

```
> var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

get object by using firabase realtimedatabase

```
function getAllUserData(func){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      let val = firebase.database().ref('users/');
      val.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      arr2 = Object.entries(Object.assign({},snapshot.val()))
      }).then(()=>{
        func(arr2);
      });

    } else {
    }
    });
}
```

React Class

```
class CheckBoxesGroup extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {randData:this.props.randData}
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
  }
  componentDidMount = ()=>{
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    getAllUserData(dispatch(setArr))
  }

  toggleCheckbox = label => {
    if (this.selectedCheckboxes.has(label)) {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.delete(label);
    } else {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.add(label);
    }
  }

  handleFormSubmit = formSubmitEvent => {
    formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();

    for (const checkbox of this.selectedCheckboxes) {
      console.log(checkbox, 'is selected.');
    }
  }
  getSelectedCheckbox = ()=>{

  }
  createCheckbox = array => (
    <Checkbox
            label={arrayl[1].time}
            handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
            key={array[1].value}
            money ={array[1].value}
            no ={arrayl[1].no}
            checked = {this.getSelectedCheckbox.bind(this)}
        ></Checkbox>
  )
  createCheckboxes = () => {
    const {randData} = this.state
    return(randData.map((array)=><Checkbox
            label={array[1].time}
            handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
            key={array[1].value}
            money ={array[1].value}
            no ={array[1].no}
            checked = {this.getSelectedCheckbox.bind(this)}
        ></Checkbox>))
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            {this.createCheckboxes()}// CheckBoxes col
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



class Checkbox extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isChecked: false,
  }
  toggleCheckboxChange = () => {
    const { handleCheckboxChange, label } = this.props;
    this.setState(({ isChecked }) => (
      {
        isChecked: !isChecked,
      }
    ));
    handleCheckboxChange(label);
  }

  render() {
    const { label,no,money} = this.props;
    const { isChecked } = this.state;
    this.state = {isChecked:false};//
    return (
      <div className="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            value={label}
                            checked={isChecked}
                            onChange={this.toggleCheckboxChange}
                            money={money}
                        />
          {label}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ReactDOM

```
ReactDOM.render(
<CheckBoxesGroup randData={arr2}/>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any good idea of doing what you want. You can only initiate fetching before render with `componentWillMount` but `render` method does not wait fetch to finish its job and you see an empty data anyhow. This is why you should use `componentDidMount` as you do in your app since `componentWillMount` will be deprecated and makes no difference in your situation

What can you do? You can use conditional rendering:

```
{this.props.randData && this.createCheckboxes()}
```

Also, do not set your props to your local state. This is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after dispatching getAllUserData in componentDidmount.